# How to install PHP GMP on macOS High Sierra?

Tags: php, composer-php, homebrew, macos-high-sierra

I am trying to install and enable GMP extension for PHP.

```
Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.5
PHP Version: 7.1.16
Composer version: 1.6.5
Homebrew version: 1.6.9
```

I am getting this error when I run `composer install`.

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested PHP extension ext-gmp * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gmp extension.
```

The `composer.json` has dependency on `"ext-gmp": "*"` . I have tried following things:

1. `brew install homebrew/php/php70-gmp`
2. `brew install gmp`
3. `brew install homebrew/homebrew-core/php70-gmp`
4. Changed in `php.ini` to enable `extension=php_gmp.dll`

I'm still getting the same error on composer install. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Did you try `brew install php71-gmp`?

Comment: It says `Error: No available formula with the name "php71-gmp" `

Answer (score 3):

Start Again. Install PHP 7

`brew install php@7.1`

add php path to `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zshrc` :

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.1/bin:$PATH"
```

then source file, start php and check gmp has been loaded

```
brew services start php@7.1
source ~/.zshrc
php -info | grep "GMP"
```

Try Again

Comment: Do I have to install php again? I have followed this guide - https://websitebeaver.com/set-up-localhost-on-macos-high-sierra-apache-mysql-and-php-7-with-sslhttps

Everything else is working fine.

Comment: try this and then do above step again `sudo apachectl restart`

Comment: I have not installed PHP via brew. High Sierra already comes with PHP 7.1 installed. I'm using that.

Comment: In my mac I install composer via help of this [link](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-osx) try this method if you just want to install composer.

Comment: I have installed composer successfully. It's failing when I'm trying to install dependencies of my project using composer.

Comment: I checked my php.ini file. I found this their 
`extension=gmp.so`

Comment: Please explain that further. According to the question, PHP is already installed. Adding it to the path will not enable GMP. And if Composer states that GMP is missing, running `php -info`  won't install it either